# Warp/WAI Internal Exception Handling

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-warp

I am developing a Warp / WarpTLS application and a bunch of middleware (without yesod), all of which handles its own exceptions.

Currently I want to deal with Exceptions raised within Warp and WarpTLS and I am unclear about what exceptions can occur and if a handler provided to `setOnException` is sufficient to handle **all** exceptions (including TLS exceptions for instance).

Here is what I understand:

1. [setOnException](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.10/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#v:setOnException) can be used to catch warp-internal exceptions (as well as application exceptions) according to the doc
2. Warp exposes [InvalidRequest](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.10/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#t:InvalidRequest) with an `Exception` instance.
3. Inspecting the src of [defaultOnExceptionResponse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.10/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#v:defaultOnExceptionResponse) suggests that `ConnectionError` may be raised from within Warp.

My questions:

1. If I provide a handler to `setOnException` can I be sure **all** internal exceptions will end up there?
2. Does 1) hold true even if I use WarpTLS and `runTLS`?
3. What kind of exceptions may be thrown by `runSettings` (Warp) and `runTLS` (WarpTLS)?

Comment: Please keep it to one question at a time.

Comment: Well I can formulate this as a single question but I thought answering it may be easier being split up in small fragments. Should I make three separate posts with all this preamble or what?